# Grant connect to all DATABASES

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've seen there's a way to grant select to all tables within a database, however I can't seem to find a way to grant connect to all databases.

I can't manually do:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE X TO readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE Y TO readonly;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE Z TO readonly;
```

so on so forth, as I have many databases.

Is there an equivalent to something like:
`GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE * TO readonly;`

My overall hope, is to grant connect and read only (select access) to the readonly user of this database to certain members of my organisation.

Best Regards,
Neil D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `psql`, you can use `\gexec`:

```
SELECT format('GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE %I TO readonly;', datname) FROM pg_database \gexec
```

`\gexec` interprets each line of the query result as an SQL statement and executes it.

Comment: A little explanation on this will query will be helpful for beginners.


Thanks.

Comment: @AATHITHRAJENDRAN I have added an explanation. But that would have been easy to find in the `psql` documentation.

Comment: cool, that's nice of you.

Answer (score 1):

For pg **14**:

`GRANT pg_read_all_data TO your_user;`

Then it can connect to all database, as **read-only**.

**Tips**:

- Seems the user can still create tables for itself in `public` schema, though can't write existing tables owned by other user.

Comment: This assumes `pg_read_all_data` is an available role.